# Clean way of checking for a "nil" String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a scenario where I'm specifically looking for a `String` with the value of `"nil"`. In short, I have a conditional where I want to pass `nil` if the user selects that option in the dropdown and not pass `"nil"`, which is what gets passed in the params:

My Select:

```
<select name="parent_id"> 
  <option name="All">All</option>
  <option name="None" value="nil">None</option>
</select>
```

My condition:

```
if params[ :parent_id ].present?
  Child.where( parent_id: params[ :parent_id ] ) # I want this to be IS NULL when params[ :parent_id ] == "nil"
end
```

Typically, you would use `.nil?` or `.blank?` on a `String` to check for a `nil` value or an empty `String`. But `"nil".nil?` and `"nil".blank?` both equal `false`, as they should.

So I'm curious if there's a good way to check for a `String` being `"nil"`.

Currently I'm using `myString == "nil"` but that leads to things like `( myString == "nil" ? nil : myString )`.

```
if params[ :parent_id ].present?
  parent_id = params[ :parent_id ] == "nil" ? nil : params[ :parent_id ]
  Child.where( parent_id: parent_id )
end
```

That's fine when it's used once in a while but if this is being used frequently, it's not ideal.

This a fairly rare occurrence, I know, but it was particularly difficult to Google so I thought I would ask SO.

My initial thoughts are:

- Add a method to `String` so you could do something like `"nil".nil_literal? #=> true`.
- Monkey patch `.presence?` so that `"nil".presence?` returns `nil` instead of `"nil"`.

Comment: If you can make client side changes, you can send a request body with `application/json` content type, and send something like {"parent_id": null, ...}
Rails coerces it to `nil`.
However, relying on client this much doesn't sound like a solid solution

Comment: @SujanAdiga Thanks for the suggestion. We have full control of the client side in this case so something worth considering. What's necessary to change on the Rails view side to make this change?

Comment: Don't monkey patch. Use OOP; one class implements the parent_id as nil depending the conditions you need, the other as it's.

Comment: @ Joshua Pinter, you will have to add event listener for submit action of the enclosing form, and then post the form using XHR

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to change the select to:

```
  <option name="None" value="">None</option>
```

If you can't do it - I'd refrain from monkey patching.

You can add `"nil"` checking to conditions:

```
if params[ :parent_id ].present? && params[ :parent_id != 'nil' 
  Child.where(parent_id: params[:parent_id]))
end
```

or you can filter the `params` in a separate method:

```
def filtered_params
  @filtered_params |= params.tap{|p| p[:parent_id] = nil if p[:parent_id] == 'nil' }
end
```

and use `filtered_params` instead of `params` in your controller code.

Comment: I can't change the "blank" option as I'm using that to indicate "All" parents (i.e. no filter whatsoever).

Comment: If not, try the other two solutions.

Comment: I don't find those other two methods any more elegant than `( params[ :parent_id ] == "nil" ? nil : params[ :parent_id ] )`.

Comment: _De gustibus non est disputandum_  IMO nesting ternary operator related to HTTP params inside an AR query is not very readable.

Comment: In fairness, I set the `parent_id` separately with `parent_id = params[ :parent_id ] == "nil" ? nil : params[ :parent_id ]` and then just pass it in with `Child.where( parent_id: parent_id )`.

Comment: I don't know what you do in your code, I just answer your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would go about it

```
class Child 
  belongs_to :parent 

  scope :by_parent, ->(parent_id=nil) { 
    parent_id.to_i == 0 ? without_parent : where(parent_id: parent_id.to_i)
  }
  scope :without_parent, -> { where(parent_id: nil) } 
end
```

then your controller code is simply

```
 Child.by_parent(params[:parent_id])
```

Comment: Yes, this seems like a more Rails way to handle "nil" values in a conditional. I'll keep mulling it over.